# How to use pandas in python to compare cells?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

So I want to compare two different cells to see

```
[ABC] x=1 y=101 Len=0 
[ABC] x=2 y=101 Len=0
```

I just want to compare the first cell with the second to see if the value of x is same or different. "[ABC] x=1 y=101 Len=0" is all in one cell.

I tries using this statement but it doesnt work,

```
if (info[i] in (info[i+1])):
   A = A+1
```

Comment: Do you have an excel file containing data in first column only and cells contain data with format like"[ABC] x=1 y=101 Len=0"?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the dataframe structure then it will be better to get a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each cell in a different variable then do some splits to compare.

```
cell1 = "[ABC] x=1 y=101 Len=0"
cell2 = "[ABC] x=2 y=101 Len=0"
cell1xValue = cell1.split(' ')[1].split('=')[1] # cell1xValue = 1
cell2xValue = cell2.split(' ')[1].split('=')[1] # cell2xValue = 2
print(cell1xValue == cell2xValue)
```

To clarify, the splits I am suggesting will first split by space.

```
cell1.split(' ') --> ["[ABC]", "x=1", "y=101", "Len=0"]
```

I get the 2nd item with array indexing syntax [1]. ("x=1")

Then the second split on that will split by equals sign

```
"x=1".split('=') --> ["x", "1"]
```

The 2nd item in this list is the value of x we want to compare.